# Receving 502 Bad Gateway when trying to access via URL

Tags: database

Unable to access my VM using SSH and receiving `502 Bad Gateway` when trying to access via URL.
Get below error :

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent", "bootCounter":"35", "lateBootReportEvent":{…}}
```

Answer (score 0):

502 means the request when to the proxy but having an issue connecting to the server

more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502

since you can't ssh also it is likely your VM is down, since you are using GCP you can check your VM status on your GCP console on compute engine -> VM instances